# Lots of items are missing in system settings, what should I do?

Tags: system-settings

I don't know when this happened, but lots of configuration items are missing

[image]

What should I install?

Specifically I need to configure the keyboard settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the items present in system settings are nothing but apps, shown in a common place for users convenience.

If you need a app(say keyboard settings), then search for the name in Ubuntu Software Center, and install the relevant app.

In this case, it is called `Keyboard` a.k.a `unity-control-center`.

You can also install it by typing the following command in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
```

It will automatically show up in system-settings.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have removed some packages by mistake. Use this and reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```